# how to do testing with a timeout in shell

Tags: shell

I want to be able to do a test with a timeout, for example, based on whether fetching a webpage is successful or not, in SHELL. How can I do this?

Answer (score -1):

I do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
TIMEOUT=5
((sleep $TIMEOUT && kill $$ &> /dev/null) & yourCommand --with arguments)
```

Comment: Thanks. Should "yourCommand --with arguments" be a conditional command? In general, I want to write a conditional statement. Could you give an explicit example?

Comment: "yourCommand --with arguments" would be in your example, the command which fetches a website and should be terminated after a given timeout. What conditional statement do you mean?

Comment: I mean, `if [[ get_website == "" && time<$TIMEOUT]] then ... else ... fi` things like this.

Comment: Do you know the answer? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't got much time. It seems that my solution isn't really the one to handle conditional statements…

Comment: If so, would you remove or modify your answer, since it is not relevant here?